# How to specify analyzer per field instance using in Elastic using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm migrating from Lucene to Elastic (6.2.4).
Today we index multi-language values on the same field (with the same name) by using different analyzers.

For example, the field "MovieName" will be indexed using EnglishAnalyzer if the movie name is in English and using SpanishAnalyzer is the movie name is in Spanish.

When the user search I analyze his query terms based on the query terms language (English terms using EnglishAnalyzer and Spanish terms using SpanishAnalyzer).

We do it by using the Field.setTokenStream when we index the field.

On Elastic it seems that we need to specify the analyzer per field (static declaration) when creating the index.
I could not find how to specify it during indexing.

This is a limitation of Elastic? NEST? or I'm missing something?

Comment: NEST docs contain [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/multi-fields.html#_creating_multi_fields) example which should be quite useful in your case. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve the problem. in this example, elastic will index the text with all the languages all the time.